# Postfix issue Relay access denied through telnet

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

Getting error relay access denied on a CentOS server with postfix and dovecot installed, trying to set up a catchall email on a CentOS 7 server. Fresh installation, installed Nano text editor and nothing else, pretty much a clean server in case it matters.

error im getting:

```html
[root@accountcreator ssl]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.tmkiller.site ESMTP Postfix
EHLO howdy.com
250-mail.tmkiller.site
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: testAccount
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: myEmail@gmail.com
454 4.7.1 <myEmail@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

My main.cf file:

```html
myhostname = mail.mydomain.site
mydomain = mydomain.site
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetwor$
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.crt
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Yes, i have replaced mydomain.site with my actual domain.

/etc/hosts file:

```html
127.0.0.1 AccountCreator AccountCreator
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 AccountCreator AccountCreator
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdom$
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdom$
serverIP mail.mydomain.site
```

I've tried reinstalling the OS and starting all over through this guide:
https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7/

I've tried googling around, tried suggestions on several Stack Overflow threads, didn't manage to find a fix that resolved this issue.

I would like to get anything@mydomain.com to forward to catchall@mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `smtpd_relay_restrictions` to allow your domain to send mail through, as it stands it appears your configuration is to only receive emails to your domain.

While you're at it, you should also configure `smtpd_client_restrictions` and `smtpd_sender_restrictions` too.

Another thing, if this is centos 7, install roundcube instead of squirrelmail for web mail.  It's simpler to maintain and looks cooler.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, under mynetworks you should add the IP address of your server

reload the postfix configuration.

There are other "best practices" how to accomplish this with hash: files for example, so you don't hardcode anything into your configuration, but have separate files that you can administer.

You can read more about it at the postfix official documentation [here](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types)

also this looks like a typo permit_mynetworks:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetwor$
```